# Unity, Как сделать объект дочерним другому объекту

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объект, который не существует на сцене, а сохранён как Prefab(сфера), спавнится каждый раз, когда игрок нажимает на ЛКМ. Только нужно сделать, чтобы Частица была дочерним объектом спавнящейся сферы.

Comment: через transform.SetParent(здесь transform объекта). вот ссылка на доку [ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Учитывая, что речь идёт о прифабе можно указывать сразу `Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html